# Shall I Delete default(system) indices of elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Greetings.! I'm facing one issue. Currently i'm using elasticsearch version 7.2 and i have 5 data nodes and 3 master nodes.When i try to login i'm getting this error.
"at least one primary shard for the index [.security-7] is unavailable". When I checked for status i have 11 unassigned shards. Those unassigned shards are belongs to the indices .security,.triggered_watches,.watches. So I planned to delete these indices. will that work for me? Kindly provide the suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-allocation-explain.html

Comment: In my case i'm not able to load kibana, hence i'm unable to execute quires.Any other suggestions pls?

Comment: Most of them are simply get queries, You can hit these queries using a browser, CURL, Postman, etc also.